# How do I get astropy Column to store string of any length?

Tags: python, string, ascii, astropy

I'm generating a few catalogues, and would like to have a column for comments. For some reason, when I generate the column and try to store a comment it only takes the first character.

```
from astropy.table import Column

C1 = Column(['']*12, name = 'ID')
C1[4] = 'test comment'
```

Then

```
print C1[4]
>> t
```

Looking at C1, I see that `<Column name='ID' dtype='str1' length=12>`
so it's obviously only storing a 1 char string.

if I try

```
C2 = Column(['some really long silly string']*12, name = 'ID')
C2[4] = 'test comment'
```

then

```
print C1[4]
>> test comment
```

but again, I can only store up to a 29 char string because `<Column name='ID' dtype='str29' length=12>` and this is a terrible solution anyway.

How do I tell Column to store any length string?

Comment: Related: [numpy recarray strings of variable length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108837/numpy-recarray-strings-of-variable-length). You could use `Column(['']*12, name = 'ID', dtype=np.object)` for example.

Comment: It's interesting that this seems to work. If I set `dtype=np.str` it defaults to `str1` still. If you can't think of another workaround without generalising to `np.object` then you should submit this as an answer.

Comment: Tables like this (numpy's recarray, Pandas' dataframe) are made for some fixed type (~fixed memory allocation), which is why there is no generic (variable) string type. Eg, Pandas will infer an `object` when you initialize a column with strings.

Comment: Using `object`, you will potentially lose utilities like string comparison. To avoid that, you could simply use a long string for the column type.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case I usually first collect the data as a Python list of strings and then call the `astropy.table.Column` constructor.

```
>>> from astropy.table import Column
>>> data = ['short', 'something longer']
>>> Column(data=data, name='spam')
<Column name='spam' dtype='str3' length=2>
  a
bbb
```

The `Column` will convert your data to a Numpy array with fixed width `dtype` for strings of the appropriate length (and left pad shorter strings with spaces).

Similarly, when constructing `astropy.table.Table` objects, I usually first collect the data as a Python list of dicts of row data, and then let the `Table` constructor figure out the appropriate `dtype` automatically.

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> rows = [{'ham': 42, 'spam': 'a'}, {'ham': 99, 'spam': 'bbb'}]
>>> table = Table(rows=rows, names=['spam', 'ham'])
>>> table
<Table length=2>
spam  ham 
str3 int64
---- -----
   a    42
 bbb    99
```

Of course this isn't super fast or memory-efficient, but for my applications it's good enough.

More generally, note that working with strings stored in Numpy arrays (which is what `astropy.table.Column` is doing) simply is painful (in my opinion, no offense intended to Numpy developers or people that like it). The best support I'm aware of for this comes from `pandas`, so you could use `pandas` to work with your data and use the `to_pandas` and `from_pandas` method of `astropy.table.Table` if you need an Astropy table, e.g. to read / write to FITS files or do something else that `pandas.DataFrame` doesn't support.