# List of tuples to numpy array - mixed types, unicode conversion not working

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of tuples in "text, integer" format, where the text is unicode and comes from a file opened with `utf-8` encoding.

I'm trying to convert the list to a numpy multidimensional array with the types kept right.

Using normal `np.array` or `np.asarray`, converts everything to unicode or U1

```
tuples = [("A",1),("B",2)]
np.array(tuples)
>>> [['A' '1']
    ['B' '2']]
```

Specifying the types I want gives me a blank string and not multi-dimensional:

```
np.array(tuples, dtype=np.dtype("U,int"))
>>> [('', 1) ('', 2)]
```

Unless I specify a number of characters to the unicode, which I cannot do because my text is of a variable length. Also this is not multi-dimensional.

```
np.array(tuples, dtype=np.dtype("<U99,int"))
>>> [('A', 1) ('B', 2)]
```

How can I convert my list of tuples to a numpy array with an integer and string format? Also, eventually, I will be doing a `np.where()` on the second column and checking if value is greater than e.g. 50, so a solution that works with the next step would be ideal. Thank you!

edit: Ideally, the result should be a multi-dimensional array so that the individual columns can be selected on their own if needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy recarray strings of variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108837/numpy-recarray-strings-of-variable-length)

Comment: Also see another linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1664917/8033585

Comment: Why do you want it to be multidimensional?  The first dimension will be records.  The named fields replace the columns of a common 2d array.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought it would be easier to later use `np.where` to select the "rows" I want if the array was multidimensional. Otherwise it's a 1D array of tuples and I can't access the first value of each tuple without first making a copy like `array[:,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to select a reasonable unicode string length.

```
In [172]: alist = [('A',1),('Beta', 2), ('Gamma', 3)]
```

for example, to get the length the strings in the list:

```
In [173]: dt1 = np.array([row[0] for row in alist]).dtype
In [174]: dt1
Out[174]: dtype('<U5')
In [175]: dt = np.dtype([('label',dt1),('value', int)])
In [176]: dt
Out[176]: dtype([('label', '<U5'), ('value', '<i8')])

In [177]: arr = np.array(alist, dt)
In [178]: arr
Out[178]: 
array([('A', 1), ('Beta', 2), ('Gamma', 3)],
      dtype=[('label', '<U5'), ('value', '<i8')])
```

to use the name fields:

```
In [179]: arr['label']
Out[179]: array(['A', 'Beta', 'Gamma'], dtype='<U5')
In [180]: arr['value']%2==1
Out[180]: array([ True, False,  True])
```

Usually we don't need a multidimensional structured array.

If the data is in a csv style file, we could let `genfromtxt` choose the string field size:

```
In [181]: txt = """A 1
     ...: Beta 2
     ...: Gamma 3"""
In [182]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None,encoding=None)
In [183]: data
Out[183]: 
array([('A', 1), ('Beta', 2), ('Gamma', 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Is there no way of doing this as a multi-dimensional array? That way I could easily select all of the first column letters if I wanted, or all of the second column values separately too. Because this way I'd have to iterate through the array and split the tuples using list comprehension or similar if I needed them

Comment: I showed how to select the string field and the numeric one.  You may need to read up on structured arrays.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had confused name fields with something else. This answered my question well, thank you. Small question, is there a difference between setting dtype to `int` vs `np.dtype("int")`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in linked questions ([numpy recarray strings of variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108837/8033585), [Automatic string length in recarray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1664917/8033585)), declare first type as `object`:

```
np.array([("A", 1), ("B", 2)], dtype=[('str', np.object), ('int', np.int)])
```